# How to recover env.php file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configuration, database-connection

is there any way to recover the env.php file. As my file deleted unexpectedly when editing using command line. Now file is empty and showing with 0 size in the ftp.  As i don't have the backup of the file or database credentials.

Any way to recover it ?

Comment: Do you have that website files on local machine?

Comment: which hosting you are using?

Comment: no i don't have that in my local drive. also i have no idea about hosting.

Comment: i only have the FTP credentials and SSH access.

Comment: do you have root ssh?

Comment: Yes i have the root SSH access.

Comment: env.php stores sensitive information, this information is not saved anywhere else by Magento. This rather turns into a more general question. How(if possible) to retrieve information that got lost in the manner specified by you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out about your hosting. If working on host might be worth reaching out to host to see if they have a restore procedure in place. The fact that you know what file and when you deleted it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

as experience shows, you just make sure your `env.php` file is writeable.
restore or create new password for database user, from phpmyadmin or mysql shell,
for example it will look like this:

```
mysql$> select user,host from mysql.user;
+-----------------+-----------+
| user            | host      |
+-----------------+-----------+
| magento         | localhost |
| mysql.session   | localhost |
| mysql.sys       | localhost |
| root            | localhost |
+-----------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

change password for example user `magento`

```
mysql$> ALTER USER 'magento'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

> backup all your files and db.

remove all caches:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* generated/* var/view_preprocessed/*
```

open your website, you will be redirected to `/setup/`, enter all your required information for re-install.

make sure there is **NO** any checkboxes selected to wipe database data.

after final install button, your config will be re-stored/re-created.
you will be able to access your shop.